# Webdriver IO automation test cases failing for firefox

Tags: webdriver-io

I am trying to write automation test cases using Webdriver IO framework. I see that when i try to use the below code

```
browser.setLocalStorage('key', value)
```

It is running fine and passing the test cases in Chrome browser
But while executing the test cases in Firefox browser, it is throwing error as 
`browser.setLocalStorage is not a function`.

So is there anything we need to do here. I am just trying to learn webdriver and starting with small test cases which sets the local storage and gets the localstorage values and updating it.

Comment: Dude, close the question if it helped you close the issue. (_green check next to answer_). Else, let's debug this ... are you still stuck?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to search through both the [wdio-v4 API](http://v4.webdriver.io/api.html), as well as the [wdio-v5 API](https://webdriver.io/docs/api.html) and I cannot find anything on `setLocalStorage` being attached to the `browser` instance. Are you referring to the [localStorage](http://v4.webdriver.io/api/protocol/localStorage.html) 
 *wdio-v4 API* method?

Is your `.setLocalStorage()` method a custom command you defined? And if so, can you update the question with its definition? Also it would help if you would add a small snippet with the relevant `package.json` dependencies.

Anyways, if you're in the market for making this work cross-browser, then you can achieve this via the [execute](https://webdriver.io/docs/api/browser/execute.html) command:

```
browser.execute('localStorage.setItem(key, value);');
```

Hope it helps!

**!Note:** The command you're trying to use will eventually call (*behind the scenes, you can check WDIO logs*), the same `localStorage` command via `execute`. So you're better of using it as is!